# Is there easy way for API creation?

Tags: ios, api, cross-platform, backend, mobile-application

I want to create a mobile app. My frontend design is ready and for backend database structure I am using MySql. But the API creation is little tough for me.

Is there any easy way to create an API without much trouble?

I do not have much time to learn new programming language and implement backend logic. It would be great if there any platform or software which facilitates this without any coding efforts or a language which takes less learning efforts to implement the same?

Comment: do you have knowledge about any server side language?

Comment: Please be more specific: what languages do you prefer for the backend? What kind of API is it and what protocol are you looking to use?

Comment: If you don't have much knowledge about back-end coding then use drag and drop API creation tool as like  http://www.configure.it/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Swift, I recommend you to use [Perfect](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect) or [Vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor) to create your API.

There is a lot of tutorial to help you like this one of Ray Wenderlich: https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/77-server-side-swift-with-perfect/lessons/1